# Cannot install MakerBundle

Tags: symfony, bundle, symfony-3.4

I'm trying to install the MakerBundle for Symfony (3.4) [as stated in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html).

The command I run is:

```
composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev
```

But I got this:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   Package symfony/maker-bundle at version  has a PHP requirement
>   incompatible with your PHP version (5.6)
>
> Checking my php version ( php -v ) gives :
>
> PHP 7.0.27-0+deb9u1 (cli) (built: Jan  5 2018 13:51:52) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright
>   (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.27-0+deb9u1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans

Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe `PHP cli version` is good but not the `PHP server version`

Comment: This is what php -i brings ( first few lines ... ) phpinfo()
PHP Version => 7.0.27-0+deb9u1

System => Linux myServer 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02) x86_64
Build Date => Jan  5 2018 13:51:52
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/7.0/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,

Comment: It is possibile that you have missed to install flex?

Comment: Fix is missing.  But I got the same error. Reading deeper the Symfony documentation, I found this                                                   https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/flex.html. where it is explained how to install flex ( it is needed to do some adjustments ).  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the **php** version inside **composer.json** file.
`"config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.2"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },`

Find the above code in ***composer.json*** file in you symfony project root directory.

**There will be 5.6 in your case just change it to 7.2**

Then again run your command it'll work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In order to install maker-bundle, it is required to use the new project structure.
There are two options :

- create the project with the new template : composer create-project 
  symfony/skeleton my-project
- follow the instructions as stated in https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/flex.html to convert the project's structure and then be able to install flex and maker.